# installing python2.7 using virtualenv in ubuntu-lucid

Tags: python, ubuntu, virtualenv

I have `python2.6` on `ubuntu lucid`.I have installed virtualenv 1.8.2 for python2.6 .There is the `virtualenv-1.8.2-py2.6.egg` in `/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages` folder.

I want to install python2.7 using virtualenv so I can test some of my code.How do I go about this?I tried

```
virtualenv venv27 --distribute --no-site-packages --python=python2.7
```

which gave an error like

```
The executable python2.7 (from --python=python2.7) does not exist
```

Please tell me how to go about this? Do I have to upgrade my O.S ?

Comment: Do you have Python 2.7 installed?

Comment: no I only have python2.6 that comes with lucid

Comment: You'll need to install Python 2.7 in order to use it inside of Virutalenv.

Comment: You have to install Python27, either by compiling it yourself or using a ppa like [deadsnake ppa](https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/deadsnakes). Then you can use virtualenv with python27

Answer (score 0):

`virtualenv` does not download or install Python (different from Ruby's `rvm`).

When you specify what python you want `virtualenv` to be based on (`--python=PYTHON_BIN`), that executable must exist. `virtualenv` uses that python installation to create its symlinks, shebangs, and everything.

As @Blender and @Dikei told you, you must have Python 2.7 before you create your `virtualenv`.